# Why we shift target(output) by one offset in language modelling

Tags: keras, nlp, rnn, language-model

I have been working in sequence prediction tasks (very similar to language modelling)  where I want to predict the next token(s)/item(s) given past sequence of tokens. I have always taken an approach like the below for data preparation

```
[0,1,2,3] -> [4]
[4,5,6,7] -> [8]
```

or

```
[0,1,2,3] -> [4,5,6,7]
[4,5,6,7] -> [8,9,10,11]
```

I have recently seen people taking output/target as one offset shifted from X. Since the goal of language modelling is to predict next token. Why and in which situation would one use this data format?

For example a famous book D2l.ai provide [example](http://d2l.ai/chapter_recurrent-neural-networks/language-models-and-dataset.html) format of the data as

```
X:  [[27. 28. 29. 30. 31.]
 [12. 13. 14. 15. 16.]]
Y: [[28. 29. 30. 31. 32.]
 [13. 14. 15. 16. 17.]]
```

Isn't it predicting token `28` after tokens `[27. 28. 29. 30. 31.]`wheras actaly Y(output) should be `[32]` or `[32,33,34,...]` ?

How would next prediction (which actually is `32`) be retrieved after token `31`?

Comment: Kindly let me know if this question is more suited for other statckexhange platform

Comment: it is simply a format for time-based seuqences (and not specific to language sequences). It may work better in some cases, given a series of predictions may better predict a single value or even the next series

Comment: One may select a single value from the output series in case the output is a series (eg 1st or last one)

Comment: Nikos, Thankyou for the comment. Your second comment (taking last index from predcition) makes sense. Can you please elaborate more on first comment ( "given a series of predictions may better predict a single value or even the next series ")

Comment: It was found to work, I have no other theoretical explanation at this point

Comment: Also, for taking one offset shifted, wouldnt network give good accuracy as it will simple learn to predict a shifted value? (but that would not be the case actually)

Comment: This makes sense.

Comment: Nikos, Okay, I meant i didnt get "next series" part of thing. Do you mean feeding it back for the next prediction in an autoregressive manner?

Comment: No, not necessarily, no feedback is needed. But having a shifted series as target output (as hinted above) has benefits sometimes, it was found to work

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Lets see if we can get a theoretically reason for this as ana snwer from someone :)